# Setting up routes in ASP.NET Core 3 MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have an ASP.NET Core 3 MVC web app and I have a couple of controllers.

I am trying to form my links to access these controllers and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Controller names: `Exhibitors`, `DemoQueue`

Each controller has an `Index` action which takes 2 `int` type parameters

```
public IActionResult Index(int eventId, int companyId)
```

And here is my relevant `Startup.cs` code

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

So it is my understanding that I can browse to these 2 actions by these urls:

```
Exhibitors/1/2
DemoQueue/3/4
```

But it seems I have to use this longwinded value:

```
Exhibitors/Index?eventId=1&companyId=2
```

Is there a way to set a route to enable me to go to `[controller]/id/id` ? But go to a different controller e.g. `Exhibitors` or `DemoQueue`

Comment: You can always use attributes on controllers/actions to customise the routing engine, you don't need to follow the _default_ route. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-constraint-reference

Comment: I read that attribute routes should  be left for rest apis ?

Comment: That's what you're doing. The only difference between "Rest APIs" and "Websites" is that websites mostly use GET verbs and return HTML instead of json/xml. It's the same thing under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't have your custom route template defined. In your `startup.cs`, all you had was the default routing template.

To map requests like `Exhibitors/1/2` and `DemoQueue/3/4` to their corresponding controllers `Index` method, you need to add the following before the default conventional routing template:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "exhibitors-custom",
        pattern: "exhibitors/{eventId:int}/{companyId:int}",
        defaults: new { controller = "exhibitors", action = "index" }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "demoqueue-custom",
        pattern: "demoqueue/{eventId:int}/{companyId:int}",
        defaults: new { controller = "demoqueue", action = "index" }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

[image]

[image]

#### Mixed routing

You can mix the use of conventional routing and attribute routing, but it's typical to use conventional routes for controllers returning HTML for browsers, and attribute routing for controllers serving RESTful APIs.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing

Comment: Perfect. This helped me figure out how to setup an endpoint that was /Report/001

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to these

```
public class ExhibitorsController:Controller
[Route("~/Exhibitors/{eventId}/{companyId}")]
public IActionResult Index (int eventId, int companyId)

and

public class DemoQueueController:Controller
[Route("~/DemoQueue/{eventId}/{companyId}")]
public IActionResult Index (int eventId, int companyId)
```